# How to build LLVM/Clang for ARM using build-llvm.sh ndk script?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, android-ndk, clang, toolchain

I'm going to compile LLVM/Clang for ARM android (target and host) using `%ndk_r9%/build/tools/build-llvm.sh` script. By default it compiles extracted toolchain sources (using `download-toolchain-sources.sh` script), but it should be modified to change host to ARM. How can that be done correctly?